# cmake on Windows: get ctest to execute command instead of running exe

Tags: windows, cmake

I have a ctest that runs a custom command instead of running an executable. On Linux the ctest runs the command successfully, but on Windows, ctest interprets the command as an executable and tries to find it (unsuccessfully of course)

This is my CMakeLists.txt:

```
if(UNIX)
  add_test(NAME testName COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.pl ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/testName)
elseif(WIN32)
  add_test(NAME testName COMMAND "cmd.exe @cmd /k \"perl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\\script.pl ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}\\bin\\Debug\\testName.exe\"")
endif(UNIX)
```

On Linux, the command is executed correctly. But on Windows this is what I get:

```
    test 1
          Start 1: testName 
    Could not find executable cmd.exe @cmd /k "perl C:/PATH/script.pl C:/PATH/bin/Debug/testName.exe"
    Looked in the following places:
    cmd.exe @cmd /k "perl C:/PATH/script.pl C:/PATH/bin/Debug/testName.exe 
.
.
.etc
```

How can I get cmake on Windows to actually run the command instead of treating it as executable? First I was trying it without (cmd.exe @cmd /k) it really makes no difference as long as it is interpreted as an exe name, not as a cmd command.

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was doing wrong, got rid of the double quotations and it worked.

```
if(UNIX)
  add_test(NAME testName COMMAND ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/script.pl ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/bin/testName)
elseif(WIN32)
  add_test(NAME testName COMMAND perl ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}\\script.pl ${PROJECT_BINARY_DIR}\\bin\\Debug\\testName.exe)
endif(UNIX)
```